# Error when installing openssl 3.0.1 : "Can't locate IPC/Cmd.pm in @INC"

Tags: openssl, centos

When installing openssl 3.0.1 i have the error bellow :

```
cd /appli/tmp
cat openssl-3.0.1.tar.gz | gzip -d  | tar -xvf -
cd /appli/tmp/openssl-3.0.1
export ROOT_HOME_SSL=/appli/openssl
mkdir -p $ROOT_HOME_SSL/3.0.1

./config  --prefix=$ROOT_HOME_SSL/3.0.1 --openssldir=$ROOT_HOME_SSL/3.0.1 shared zlib-dynamic shared
```

> Can't locate IPC/Cmd.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
> /appli/tmp/openssl-3.0.1/util/perl /usr/local/lib64/perl5
> /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
> /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .
> /appli/tmp/openssl-3.0.1/external/perl/Text-Template-1.56/lib) at
> /appli/tmp/openssl-3.0.1/util/perl/OpenSSL/config.pm line 18. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at
> /appli/tmp/openssl-3.0.1/util/perl/OpenSSL/config.pm line 18.
> Compilation failed in require at /appli/tmp/openssl-3.0.1/Configure
> line 23. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
> /appli/tmp/openssl-3.0.1/Configure line 23.

**OS :**
CentOS release 6.7 (Final) , 2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 62):

I was finally able to solve this for myself by running...

`yum install perl-IPC-Cmd`

.... before...

`./Configure`

Hope that works for you as well!